# "IF" Statement to Filter out text beginning and ending with a certain character

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to find a way to write an "IF" statement that will search for words beginning with a "6" or "7" as well as words that end with a "C". If true I would like to return "4509 Not Billable". Thanks

This is what I have so far, but need to add an OR to the beginning:

=IF(OR(AND(LEFT(G2,1)="6",RIGHT(G2,1)="C"),LEFT(H2,1)="6",RIGHT(G2,1)="C"),"4509 Not Billable","")

Comment: What is not working with your current formula?

Comment: Some example cell entries and expected outcomes would help

Comment: The formula is working, however, I'd like to also look up "6" or "7" at the beginning of G1.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula explained:

```
=IF
( OR
  ( AND
    (  LEFT(G2,1)="6"
    ,  RIGHT(G2,1)="C"
    )
  ,  LEFT(H2,1)="6"
  ,  RIGHT(H2,1)="C"
  )
,"4509 Not Billable"
,""
)
```

Your formula says: 
if, Either

- Left = 6 And at the same time Right is C
- left = 6
- Right = C

Then... x

I've edited the answer, as your question was not that clear. To my indication you want to copy all so that it works for a 7 too. That would make your formula like so:

```
=IF
( OR
  ( AND
    (  LEFT(G2,1)="6"
    ,  RIGHT(G2,1)="C"
    )
  ,  LEFT(H2,1)="6"
  ,  RIGHT(H2,1)="C"
  , AND
    (  LEFT(G2,1)="7"
    ,  RIGHT(G2,1)="C"
    )
  ,  LEFT(H2,1)="7"
  )
,"4509 Not Billable"
,""
)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining out the conditions. There was a typo on my part in the original statement. The second set of conditions should both be referencing H2, not G2. Basically, I'm trying to search two columns for the same set of conditions. Second, I do think it needs to be an AND statement. RIGHT(G2,1)="C" must be met. But I'm trying to do an OR for the LEFT(G2,1)="6" or LEFT(G2,1)="7". I hope this makes sense. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @JChooks your initial post is not clear that the requirement for G2 need both to be true where the H2 doesn't. Does that mean the same applies for when it finds a 7?

Comment: Correct. Sorry for the confusion in the original post. I'm searching 2 columns G and H. Looking for "6" OR "7" in the beginning AND "C" at the end. If this is true I would like to return "4509 Not Billable". I hope this is cleared.

Comment: @JChooks: Please do not post comments to clarify your question — especially not *under an answer*; [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1149021/edit) your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @JChooks Feel free to mark this answer as solved so others know you no longer need help. You can do so by pressing the checkmark on the left of this answer.